# Showing that $X = \{f \in C[a,b] | f(a)=f(b)=0 \}$ is a subspace of $C[a,b].$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

We consider the closed interval to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. All I have so far is: Take $f_{1}, f_{2}$ from X. By Rolle's Theorem, there exist $c_{1}, c_{2} \in (a,b)$ such that $f_{1}\prime(c_{1})=f_{2}\prime(c_{2})=0.$ We know that the sum of two continuous functions is again continuous. What's left to prove is that $f_{1}(a) + f_{2}(a) = f_{1}(b) + f_{2}(b) = 0$. But it's not obvious to me how I can prove that the sum of these two functions is again in $X$.. Any hints?

Comment: Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $X$, then $f_1(a)=f_1(b)=0$ and $f_2(a)=f_2(b)=0$. No need of Rolle’s theorem here. Actually, we don't even know that the elements of $X$ are differentiable.

Comment: Jeez, I feel really silly. Thanks. @azif00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolle's theorem is not necessary (after all, we don't know if the functions are even differentiable!).

What you need to show is that, given $f,g \in X$, we have $\alpha f + \beta g \in X$ for any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. This constitutes three steps:

- Show that $\alpha f + \beta g$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$
- Show that $(\alpha f + \beta g)(a) = 0$ (i.e. $\alpha f(a) + \beta g(a) = 0$)
- Show that $(\alpha f + \beta g)(b) = 0$

As a hint for the latter two: if we know that $f,g \in X$, then $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ (because we start with the assumption they lie in $X$, and what axioms do functions in $X$ satisfy?).

Comment: Yeah, this is more obvious than I thought. I just over-complicated for no reason. Thanks for your help.